# Why subsequent click on children of jstree does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

i'm facing problem with `jstree` , once the data is changed `click` won't work for every subsequent `click`, i need to **refresh the page** to make it work

**here is jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg3B/2121/

i'm replacing `jstree` settings data with new data like below

```
"data" :jsondata[index]
```

> **Note:** please click on rendered child node

**below Demo:** (please use jsfiddle for full view http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg3B/2121/)

```js
var jsondata =  [
                [{
                    "data" : "A node 1",
                    "metadata" : { id : 123 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 11", "A Child 12" ]
                }],
                 [{
                    "data" : "A node 2",
                    "metadata" : { id : 223 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 21", "A Child 22" ]
                }],
                [{
                    "data" : "A node 3",
                    "metadata" : { id : 3223 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 31", "A Child 32" ]
                }]
            ]


function populateWithNewJsonData(index){
     $('#jstree').jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data" :jsondata[index]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });
} 
var i = 0;
var intid = setInterval(function(){
   i++;
   if(i >= 3) i = 0;
   console.log('tree data changed',jsondata[i]);
   populateWithNewJsonData(i);
   $('p span#spannnnnnn').text(i);
},9000);


 $("#jstree").bind(
            "select_node.jstree",
            function(evt, data) {
          
              if (data.inst._get_parent().length <= 0 || data.inst._get_parent() === -1) {
                console.log('clicked data', data.inst.get_json());
              } else {
                console.log('clicked data',data.inst.get_json());
       }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<p>
tree data changed with index : <span id="spannnnnnn"></span> data
</p>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every time you call `jstree` method DOM is destroyed and created again. So you have to assign listener again after creating new jstree. Old one just listens for click event on nodes that don't exist anymore.
Put code that binds listener for `select_node.tree`  event into `addListener` function:

```
function addListener(){
     $("#jstree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(evt, data) {

          if (data.inst._get_parent().length <= 0 || data.inst._get_parent() === -1){
            console.log('clicked data', data.inst.get_json());
          } else {
            console.log('clicked data',data.inst.get_json());
          }
     });
}
```

Create function to remove listeners before destroying jstree:

```
function removeListeners(){
    $("#jstree").unbind("select_node.jstree");
}
```

Use them:

```
function populateWithNewJsonData(index){
    removeListeners();

    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data" :jsondata[index]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });
    addListeners();
}
```

You can see these changes in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg3B/2124/)